# Windows NNTP Server Software

Tags: windows

I'd like to setup my own [NNTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) (Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) server for my intranet. What free solutions do exists? Any recommendations? I'd like to have something with a GUI, if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: what windows OS? What's wrong with the nntp server that's in Windows Server?

Comment: this question was migrated from superuser.com. i'm looking for a newsgroup server software and my windows os is currently vista.

Comment: Is NNTP really the best technology? Not to dis something just because it's old - but might a web forum and/or an RSS feed be better suited to whatever you're trying to do? How about you tell us what you're trying to do, from a "business" or "end-state" point of view?

Comment: NNTP will certainly make a come-back once people realize that Slack doesn't give them a threaded-by-default mode of communication.

Answer (score 1):

You could try http://sourceforge.net/projects/wendzelnntpd/. Been a while since I used this but it was pretty simple setup.

Answer (score 0):

We always used DNEWS, it's wasn't free but was very cheap, and it worked well for us... http://www.netwinsite.com/dnews.htm, but it looks like they've discontinued it - it's still for download, don't know if it's now free w/o a license or not, their forum's down.  You could ping them and see what the deal is.

Or you could load on a server OS and get one for free that way.